# Select xml node including its children using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big xml file (>300 mb), I am using notepad++ to find and replace using regular expression. I need to select (and remove) xml node which has multiple children across multiple lines.

```
<contact attrib="foo">
    <child 1></child1 1>
    <child 2></child1 2>
    ...
    <child n></child n>
</contact>
```

I tried searching with

```
<contact.*?</contact>
```

this only works if its all on the same line. Having trouble selecting multiple lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Are you searching for child nodes, or child nodes that span multiple lines? Try this `<contact[\s\S]*?</contact>`, instead of the regex dot `.` metachar. Should work if notepad++ suports `\S`.

Comment: `<contact[\s\S]*?</contact>` did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having lies with the engine Notepad++ uses for regular expressions. Refer to the [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad) for solutions. I've had success with this particular one in **advanced search mode**:

> Ctrl+M will insert something that matches newlines. They will be replaced by the replace string.
>   I recommend this method as the most reliable, unless you really need to use regex.

Also, if you need to edit large XML files, I'd recommend an editor like [Foxe](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) for a more intuitive workflow.

Comment: This was helpful, Due to time restrictions I ended up writting a php script to do the job. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

what you're trying to accomplish is, strictly speaking, not regular and thus can't be defined in a general way as a **regular** expression as the potential recursion depth is unlimited. See [what does regular in regex/"regular expression" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805863/what-does-regular-in-regex-regular-expression-mean) for details.

That being said, if what you're really trying to do is make your regular expression span multiple lines, most regular expression engines have a 'multi-line' option that changes how line breaks are handled (e.g., `.` means 'every character' rather than 'every character but newline'. Se your regex engine documentation for details.

Comment: He would still be able to limit the search with something  like `<contact>.+?</contact>`, but the dot not matching newline and npp not supporting newline in regex-mode prevents all attempts in this direction.